# Change USB Port Health (Connectivity) Check Interval

Tags: linux, usb, connectivity

Is there any way (in Linux) to change the interval that the system polls the USB ports for a health (connectivity) check? Or even turn off this check?

Background: I have a small box that the devices connected via USB never change. The system is on UPS, but every time there's a flicker in power the devices that don't have a battery will not fully return to service until there's manual intervention.

Thanks for any help that anyone can provide!